# Query works on database but not in memory?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

We have the following two oh-so-wonderful queries. They are identical in every way but one: one of them points at an IQueryable representing Entity Framework's connection to my local SQL server and the other represents a List which, theoretically, contains exactly the same data.

```
var databaseQuery = db.Table.First(Test);
var listQuery = list.First(Test);
```

In this case, I create list in the following manner:

```
var list = db.Table.ToList();
```

Nothing fancy. I only wanted to improve the query's abysmal performance on my dev machine by trading a few hundred megs of ram for, say, a half hour of my life that I'm never going to get back. There was only one little catch:

```
var listQuery = list.First(Test);
```

I always, always, always get an exception on that line, right there, saying that the sequence contains no matching element.

What on earth is going on?

Edit: Since you asked so nicely, the test in this case compares the value of two longs.

Further edit: Here is the *actual* code, snipped straight from the IDE. This .First() is tacked onto the end of either an IQueryable or an IEnumerable--either an in-memory pile of entities or a link to a database.

```
.First(v =>
    v.UserID == mm.SystemUserId
    && validMerchants.Contains(v.ActualMerchantId.Value));
```

Slauma: I didn't say it's never null. I only said that it being null would throw a different exception. (You know, one that makes sense.)

Looks like I'm gonna have to find a different way to speed this up.

Comment: Are you willing to spend 30 seconds of your life and add to your question what `Test` is? Predicates comparing `string`s could cause a different query result (due to case insensitivity in database and case sensitivity in memory for example). And there are probably many more explanations because LINQ-to-Entities != LINQ-to-Objects. A whole lot depends on `Test`.

Comment: What is the sql generated? (`databaseQuery.ToString()`), and can we see the definiton of `Test` in code?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer to this until you post the *code* for `Test`. The class definition for the entities in `Table` might be helpful too, because things like whether or not the `long` being tested is nullable will make a difference.

Comment: Technically, I'm pretty sure the long being tested is *not* nullable; as you can see, the comparison is not between value1 and value2, but between value1 (type `long`) and value2.Value (also type `long`). Attempting to materialize Value when there isn't a value there will fire a null reference exception instead of just returning false. (Note: that's not the exception I'm getting.)

Comment: I think, more details are needed (entity definition and table content (small example)). This predicate should do the same for db and in-memory queries (if `ActualMerchantId` is actually never `null`).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that should trigger this except, as suggested, a diferent behavior of null between both cases however i can suggest a very simple way to debug this

You said that the DB version return results but the memory one doesn't, the reverse would be harder to debug but this is easy, from the db version result set, do a .First() & note down the ID

Change the in memory one to do a .Where(check for the specific ID you know should match here from the DB set) before your .First()

Put a breakpoint INSIDE the first lambda (not on the .First() line but on the v=> line) , it should only hit what matches (since you already filtered everything else from the where). Then when on that breakpoint, copy/paste the content of the lambda to the immediate window to see why it returns false, test those untill you find something that returns false & then it should be obvious what's wrong, if it's not post the results here & we can dig this deeper.

1st test : v.UserID == mm.SystemUserId && validMerchants.Contains(v.ActualMerchantId.Value)
2nd test : v.UserID == mm.SystemUserId 
3rd test : validMerchants.Contains(v.ActualMerchantId.Value)

If any of those returns false then you know that it doesn't match, time to check that data & see why. If it all returns true well, first should return that element & you don't have a bug, so i'm fairly sure "something" will return false. Also make sure to post the result from everything if one of those return false (value of v.UserId, mm.SystemUserId, & v.ActualMerchantId.Value)